# getting .rdlc to work with dataset and report viewer

Tags: vb.net, dataset

For the last 2 days I've been trying to get this report to work. I've gone through lots of websites and such however I am still not able to get this report to work.

Here are the steps I took:

- Created new application
- Added ReportViewer1
- Added Report1.rdlc
- Created a new DataSet called DS1 - where I connect to Sql SErver, and grabbed all the neccesary tables.
- Created a parameter textbox/table

  - For ReportViewer1 - changed the report source to WindowsApplication.Report1.Rdlc
  - Also changed the Source Code (for reportViewer1) to DS1
  - Added the following code in form1 under buttonClick

---

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   Button1.Click

    Dim params(0) As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter
    params(0) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("ReportParameter1", "HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOO")
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(params)

    'Get Data
    Dim ReportDS As DataSet = GetData()
    Dim rds As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("DS1", ReportDS.Tables(0))
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
    ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

End Sub

Public Function GetData() As DataSet

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Conn.Open()
    Dim sql As String = "Select FirstN, LastN from tblCustomers"

    adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn)
    adapter.Fill(ds)

    Return ds

End Function
```

Please someone point me in the right direction - I am not sure what I am doing wrong!

If i do just the ReportParameter1 - I can see the "HELLOOO" in report viewer so I know that works, but with adding the data and whatnot it's not working the error i'm getting is....

> A data source instance has not been supplied for DataSet1

Comment: Does it work if you change this line `Dim rds As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("DS1", ReportDS.Tables(0))` to `Dim rds As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ReportDS.Tables(0))`

Comment: @tuco actually it does work - so right now it's only showing me the headings that I created in report1.rdls (basically added a table and with headings - but I do not know how to reference the DataSet1 in terms of data)

Comment: So, the problem in this question is solved? and now you have a new problem?

Comment: @tuco i'm sorry I've been working on this for days........help a brotha out

Comment: I'm asking this because if the original question is solved I can provide an answer and you can checkmark it, then we can check your new problem in a new post.

Comment: @Tuco you def got an answer now i gotta wait 90 mins

Comment: Ok I'll suply the answer, and you can start your new Post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the error message you're getting and by looking at this line:

```
Dim rds As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("DS1", ReportDS.Tables(0))
```

I can conclude that the report DataSet is defined as "DataSet" in the RDLC and you're supplying it as "DS1".

Change to:

```
Dim rds As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ReportDS.Tables(0))
```